# What's the meaning of "similar match" in source verification?

Tags: etherscan

I'm looking at a contract that shows an orange badge and reads **Contract Source Code Verified** (*Similar Match*), providing a different address (with the same code). Does anybody know what this means?

(I can't really provide the example addresses on NDA grounds :( )

Comment: I don't really understand this rule. Most of the questions here should be on the docsite of parity, solidity, geth, etc. Because they are not, we come here to ask and share what we found. How is this question different than the others?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the reply I got from [Kaven](https://twitter.com/kvrncqc) @Etherscan, in case it's useful for somebody else:

> Contract that gets the “Similar Match” annotation has the identical
>   contract code (exact bytecode) with another contract (address
>   provided) that has been deployed on the blockchain. The “Similar
>   Match” annotation does not takes constructor argument into account.
>   Contract that has the same contract code but deployed with a different
>   constructor argument will get the “Similar Match” annotation. We
>   matches the contract code on our database and display “Similar Match”
>   to the contracts that matches with another contract.
>
> As for “Exact Match”, this annotation is given to contract that is
>   verified by the owner with the exact constructor argument.